# Undefined method `update_attributes'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

Why do I get this error? I'm out of ideas.

`` undefined method `update_attributes' for # ``

Code:

```
exists = Vote.where(comment_id: @comment.id).exists?
    if exists
        update_vote = Vote.where(comment_id: @comment.id)
        update_vote.update_attributes(value: 5)
        redirect_to :back
    else
```

Comment: What this error message tells you is that your `update_vote.update_attributes` is not defined. Somewhere earlier in your code, you should define `update_attributes`, otherwise you can't use it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to fetch one record in particular, so tell it:

```
update_vote = Vote.where(comment_id: @comment.id).first
```

but this code is prone to errors if nothing matches, beware.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `find_by` instead of `where`. It will return one document instead of a `Mongoid::Criteria`, which is why you're getting that error (you're trying to run `.update_attributes`, which acts on a single record, on a group of records). Consider the following instead.

```
if update_vote = Vote.find_by(comment_id: @comment.id)
  update_vote.update_attributes(value: 5)
  redirect_to :back
else
```

The above code can also avoid an unnecessary call to `.exists?` since the existence check is right along with the definition (if `.find_by` does not find any records that match, it returns `nil`, much like `.where(...).first` would also do).